# Search working in toolbar but not in body

Tags: javascript

I am building a new template for displaying online help.

I have a search field in the toolbar and the first page which calls dhtml_search.htm and in turn dhtml_search.js with two functions that search an array and return results,

```
function show_results()
function search()
```

Searching in the toolbar works fine.

However, the same search function doesn't work when called in the [first page](http://www-int1.audatex.net/audatexhelp/Test/index.htm), I get an error on line 65 of `dhtml_search.js`:

> object required

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on line 65 when you do this:

```
var myDiv = window.top.document.getElementById("body_right");
myDiv.innerHTML = all_content;
```

You actually are "replacing yourself" with your 'all_content' variable.

This is the structure:

```
div#body_right
    iframe[name=BODY]
        iframe[name=search_body]
```

The code you are executing is in the iframe[name=search_body] and your script erases all the content in the parent div#body_right so you are destructing your own execution context.

It works in the toolbar because at that time your code does not execute from the iframe[name=search_body] but from the toolbar frame.

Hope i'm clear :-)

Comment: Put your `iframe[name=search_body]` outside of the `div#body_right` ;-)